# Is there a touch event for the Home button?

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

iPhone 6 and 6 Plus comes with a Reachability feature to pull down the screen. Is there an API to notify an app when the user double-taps the home button?

Answer (score 0):

when user double tap home button only below method will be called from AppDelegate.

1) Double tap home

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

when tap on app below method will be called

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

2) single tap below method will be called

```
1)- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
2)- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Maybe this will help you.